# Fastest way to execute a batch of SQL lines

Tags: mysql, sql, 4d-database

I'm migrating a 4D database to a MySQL database. I have around 50k - 60k of SQL lines to do this. What is the fastest way to send this to the remote db?

Because it's in development and the export changes frequently I have to run this multiple times a week.

I use `START TRANSACTION; COMMIT;` and I tried using `source`, but I'm not really impressed by the speed of the executions.

What is the approach I am looking for?

Comment: Through `mysqldump`?

Comment: Use mysqldump with tuned  parameters for it

Answer (score 0):

Export table from database:

```
mysqldump -u username –-password=password database_name > file.sql
```

Import table:

```
mysql -u username –-password=password database_name < file.sql
```